# Facebook:Blank Screen on FB Login

Tags: javascript, facebook, sdk, facebook-login

suddenly I am getting a strange thing happening in my application when trying to login via facebook. The facebook connect popup dialog will show a blank screen after asking for login details. Normally I would expect to see the window close, and then the site itself would carry on, however it appears to have hung.

I am using `Javascript SDK on Localhost`

Here is the code I'm using (copying directly from the facebook documentation):

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
    FB.init({ appId: fbAppId,
        status: false,
        cookie: true,
        xfbml: true
    });

};

(function (d) {
    var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
    js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
    ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
} (document));



$(document).ready(function () {


    $("#fb_button_login").click(function () {


        FB.login(function (response) {
            if (response.authResponse) {
                console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
                FB.api('/me', function (response) {
                    console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
                });
            } else {
                console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
            }
        });


    });

});
```

Some other notes:

- This appears to be happening on all browsers.
- I have researched all other posts and can't seem to find a solution that works for me
- There are no error messages showing up in console
- When developing I use a separate FB app ID that I have setup specifically for localhost with the designated port I'm using (has worked fine for more than 12 months)

  - I do not have sandbox mode enabled

The URL it appears to hang on is [here](https://www.facebook.com/dialog/permissions.request?_path=permissions.request&app_id=149954195086116&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fstatic.ak.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Fxd_arbiter.php%3Fversion%3D8%23cb%3Df83b52c04%26origin%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A49568%252Ff13fd2038%26domain%3Dlocalhost%26relation%3Dopener%26frame%3Df1c7b95c88&sdk=joey&display=popup&response_type=token%2Csigned_request&domain=localhost&fbconnect=1&from_login=1&client_id=149954195086116)

Thanks guys.

Comment: So this started to happen with me, and still "I have researched all other posts and can't seem to find a solution that works for me". Did you had any luck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a bug:
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/241915819261223?browse=search_4ff2ead131a032989098325

From the comments in the above link, you can try running your app on port 80 and avoid the port part in the url

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js" ></script>
<script>

FB.init({appId: fbAppId, status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true});
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#fb_button_login").click(function () {
        FB.login(function (response) {
            if (response.authResponse) {
                console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
                FB.api('/me', function (response) {
                    console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
                });
            } else {
                console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
            }
        });


    });
});

</script>
<a href="javascript://" id="fb_button_login">Login</a>
</body>
</html>
```