# Facebook JS SDK authentication window in Explorer 8

Tags: javascript, facebook, internet-explorer-8, facebook-javascript-sdk

Some of my users are trying to add my application and grant it with the scope(privileges) that I am asking for, it results in a blank screen, only at the IE8 browser, and works fine at the rest of the browsers.

I found the following posts on that topic, but they both led me towards a dead end, the one is still remains unanswered, and the other has a link which doesn't work any longer as part of the answer, which says that this was a non-browser-specific bug back in July 2012.

[SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11293494/facebookblank-screen-on-fb-login)

[Another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8103359/facebook-auth-dialog-js-sdk-returns-blank-screen)

Thanks in advance for any assistance, this is a major issue for me since my application has a lot of users that use corporate work stations and cannot determine their browser version \ type.